# How to pass arrays between vba and c# dll not using COM

Tags: c#, vba, marshalling, unmanaged, managed

Having had problems with COM in the past I want to look at other ways to call C# routines from vba (Excel).  I am using RGeisecke's DLLExport library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports/1.2.2.23707).
I have it working with simple variables, but can't figure out how to pass arrays to and from the code.  My best attempt causes excel to crash (becomes unresponsive).

Here is where I am at.
C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

class Test
{
    [DllExport("TestExport", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static int TestExport([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_ARRAY)] double[] dblTest)
    {

        return dblTest.GetLength(0);
    }
}
```

VBA:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function TestExport Lib "ClassLibrary1.dll" (ByRef dbltest() As Double) As Integer


Sub test()
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim dbltest(0 To 5, 0 To 6) As Double
MsgBox TestExport(dbltest)
End Sub
```

I believe I need to use marshalling to having it work, but am struggling to find online examples of what I am after.  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Using Giesecke's hack is a recipe for trouble, you don't get the benefit of the interop marshaller converting types for you.  The best way to interop with VBA is by using a [ComVisible] class.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I will put energy into making COM interop work.